# awk: pipe output of (conditional) print to gzip

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

consider this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
group, value
1, 3.21
1, 3.42
1, 3.5
2, 4.1
2, 4.2
EOL
```

in the following script, I group the rows of this file by 
the values in the first column (the values in the first column are already sorted) and print each group to an individual txt file:

```
var=$(echo 'example_file.txt')
var2=$(echo $var|sed "s/.txt//g")
mkdir -p output
cat $var | awk -v varn="$var2" -F, 'FNR == 1 {header = $0;next} !seen[$1]++ { print header > ("output/"varn"_"$1".txt") }{print > ("output/"varn"_"$1".txt");}'
```

**question**

How to print the result to a compressed stream `"output/"varn"_"$1".gz"` (instead of an uncompressed txt file `"output/"varn"_"$1".txt"`)?

(so the desired output is the same as that the scrip produces now, only I 
want the outputed files to be compressed and saved to `.txt.gz` instead of plain text ones as the code does now).

(I tried using `gzip >` inside the `{print}` blocks but to no avail :(

(PS I'm a bit of a an awk noob and so the question might be a really dumb one.)

Comment: FYI that's a [UUOC(Useless Use of Cat)](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and also of `echo` and `sed`: you can assign the variables simply as `var='example_file.txt'` and `varn="{var%.txt}"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe to commands in GNU awk's `print`. From [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Redirection):

> ```
> print items | command
> ```
>
> It is possible to send output to another program through a pipe
>   instead of into a file. This redirection opens a pipe to command, and
>   writes the values of items through this pipe to another process
>   created to execute command.
>
> The redirection argument `command` is actually an awk expression. Its
>   value is converted to a string whose contents give the shell command
>   to be run. For example, the following produces two files, one unsorted
>   list of peoples’ names, and one list sorted in reverse alphabetical
>   order:
>
> ```
> awk '{ print $1 > "names.unsorted"
>        command = "sort -r > names.sorted"
>        print $1 | command }' mail-list
> ```

So:

```
awk -v varn="$var2" -F, 'FNR == 1 {header = $0;next}
  !seen[$1]++ { print header | "gzip > "output/"varn"_"$1".gz" }
  {print | "gzip > output/"varn"_"$1".gz";}'
```

For example:

```
% echo 1 2 | awk '{print $2 | "gzip > "$1".gz"}'
% zcat 1.gz 
2
```

Comment: Thanks! Small problem (I think) running the corrected code (copy pasting the block after the So:) I get `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
awk: line 1: runaway string constant ");} ...`